# How to get content of another web page using hosting external server

Tags: php, html, string, hosting

I have a problem, I want to get the webpage content as text and save it to a variable, and everything works, $response contains the webpage content when I use xamp and apatche server. However, when using external hosting servers, $response contains an empty string.
I have already tried on two hosting servers.I using the same php versions (5.6) to both servers.

Here is my fragment of php code:

```
<?php
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$response = file_get_contents("https://kolejka.pulawy.powiat.pl/", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Comment: i guess the answer is in ```allow_url_fopen``` php setting, read about it https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: Hmmm, i have checked it, and i have set allow_url_fopen to On , so it could be good, but its not still

Comment: the value must be 1 or 0, not On or Off. and you must see the server error log for errors for the moment of file_get_contents execution

Comment: It looks like your SSL config is not valid. When opening the address from a browser, I get this: "The connection used to load this site used TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1, which are deprecated and will be disabled in the future. Once disabled, users will be prevented from loading this site. The server should enable TLS 1.2 or later." Try fixing that or try using curl with SSL validation turned off